# Except for null values in date format

Tags: sql, postgresql

May I know how to solve my syntax wherein I want to change the data type of my order_date column from VARCHAR to DATE format except for null values in the order_date column.

```
alter column order_date TYPE DATE USING order_date:: DATE
WHERE order_date IS NOT NULL
```

I am using pgAdmin4 6.12 version

Comment: There is no WHERE in an ALTER COLUMN statement. You should learn the difference between DDL and DML. When you alter the type of a column, it affects the entire column. There is no exception for some sort of value.

Comment: You can't change the type of a column for a subset of the rows.

Comment: It's not possible, but why would you need something like this? The name of the column, order_date, already suggests that this is a DATE.

Comment: @FrankHeikens because I am thinking of writing a "Never" to all null values in the order_date column. I can not think of any way on how to handle blank data cells. Well, the reason for the blank data cells is that there is no order for that day that is why I want to put 'Never' on the null values

Comment: @Chris: That's something I would handle in the presentation layer, not in the database.

Comment: "Never" will not work as that is not a valid `date` value. Either stick with `null` or use the `infinity` value per [DateTimes](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html) *8.5.1.4. Special Values*.

Answer (score 0):

Simply remove the `WHERE` clause. NULL is a valid value for all data types, so it might just as well be a `date`.